# HTML form - normal button prevents submitting the form on Enter

Tags: html, forms, button, submit

I have a form with some

```
<button>
```

elements and a normal

```
<input type="submit">
```

button to submit the form.

However, when I press Enter when I'm in a textfield, the form does not get submitted but much rather the first  Element is "pressed".

How can I change this behavior?

Comment: "normal button to submit" means `<input type="submit">`?

Comment: Sorry, SO filtered out the HTML buttons

Comment: Could you post the full html of the **entire** `form` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to capture that the `Enter` key was pressed and submit the form.

See [this](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/index_famsupp_157.html) example.

For a complete answer, could you please post your HTML?

Comment: Thats what I'm doing now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing the `<button>` tag and turning it into an `<input type="button" />` tag.  This should force the form to submit the way you want.